# Cannot find variable in a simple function inside a for of loop (safari)

Tags: javascript, safari

I'm trying to discover why Safari returns a console error whereas other browsers like Chrome have no problem. There is a simple function inside a for of loop as follows:

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll('ul > li > a');

console.log(links); // successful

for (const link of links) {
    console.log(link); // successful
  
  function logLink() {
    console.log(link);
  }
  
  logLink();
}
```

```html
<ul id='test'>
  <li>
    <a class='one' href='#'>test 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class='two' href='#'>test 2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class='three' href='#'>test 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/ns91/pen/oNNEKpP

Open the above codeine URL in safari and open your javascript console. As you can see, in Safari, the function `logLink();` doesn't seem to log the link variable, although it works in Chrome.

The error I'm getting is: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: link

Does anyone know why this is happening, and how to fix it?

Thanks for any help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function declarations are scoped to the function they are declared inside and hoisted (so it is *outside* the for loop's block) but `const` declarations are scoped to the containing *block*.

`link` only exists inside the block, `logLink` lives outside it, so `logLink` doesn't have access to the `link` constant.

Use a function expression and a `const` so the function is scoped to the for loop's block like the `link` constant.

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll('ul > li > a');
for (const link of links) {
  const logLink = function logLink() {
    console.log(link);
  }
  logLink();
}
```

```html
<ul id='test'>
  <li>
    <a class='one' href='#'>test 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class='two' href='#'>test 2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class='three' href='#'>test 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks - I don't understand how you've made it work since it works in other browsers and the link variable should already be available since it's define in the above scope with the for of loop