# Very simple rollover not working in Safari

Tags: javascript

I'm really trying to understand why such a simple rollover function just will not work in Safari. I created a similar post to which someone somehow made it work:

[Cannot find variable in a simple function inside a for of loop (safari)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58708552/cannot-find-variable-in-a-simple-function-inside-a-for-of-loop-safari/58708656#58708656)

However, this demo is slightly different and works in Chrome but NOT in safari for some unknown reason. Take a look at the code below:

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll('#list a'),
      display = document.querySelector('#argh');

for (const link of links) {
  link.addEventListener('mouseover', change);
  link.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  function change() {
    console.log(link);
    let color;

    switch (link.className) {
      case 'one':
        color = 'blue';
        link.classList.add('active');
        break;
      case 'two':
        color = 'green';
        link.classList.add('active');
        break;
      case 'three':
        color = 'pink';
        link.classList.add('active');
        break;
    }
    
    display.style['background-color'] = color;
  }
}
```

```css
#argh {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id='argh' style='background-color: red'>
</div>

<p> select one </p>
<ul id='list'>
  <li><a class='one' href='#'>test 1</a></li>
  <li><a class='two' href='#'>test 2</a></li>
  <li><a class='three' href='#'>test 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

You just roll your cursor over the 'test' bullet points to change the colour of the main display. I see no reason why this should not work in Safari.

Can someone shed some light and try to explain how to fix it? I honestly don't know how to fix it. From the other question I asked in the link above, the solution may be related to scoping - but if this is the case, then why does it work in other browsers already?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/ns91/pen/eYYPwVR

Thanks for any help here.

Comment: You are using arrow function syntax. Are you sure that Safari support ES6 yet?

Comment: After fixing to ES5 syntax, try to move the function change part above addEventListener. In some browser, declaring function before using it helps when it's not in a global scope. Also, declaring a function inside a loop is NO. Try another approach.

Comment: There's a console error about not finding `link`, try using a more conventional approach, i.e. convert the `querySelectorAll` result to an array and iterate with a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current code, the function `change` has no knowledge of what `link` is because it is declared in a deferent scope from the `for` loop.

you can solve by updating the `change` function to:

```js
 function change(e) {
    const link = e.target;
    console.log(link);
    let color;

...
```

working pen (tested in safari) https://codepen.io/JustH/pen/LYYgwVa

edit: your current code will also only work once, since once you add "active" to the class names, the switch statement no longer works. You want to split the string to get the class you want.